# Why are the possessive and object pronouns the same for feminine but not masculine?

Tags: etymology, pronouns, parts-of-speech

Essentially, why is the pronoun the same in different uses for feminine but not masculine?

---

### Feminine:

**Possessive:**

> It is *her* car.

**Accusative**

> I know *her*.

### Masculine:

**Possessive:**

> It is *his* car.

**Accusative:**

> I know *him*.

Comment: See [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=h&p=16&allowed_in_frame=0) for her and [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=h&p=23&allowed_in_frame=0) for his.  Hisis was used for a time, but "failed to stick".

Answer (score 2):

These pronouns follow the usual genitive and dative of Old English.

> Masculine Genitive: *his*
>
> Masculine Dative:  *him*
>
> Feminine Genitive: *hire*
>
> Feminine Dative: *hire*

There can be no good explanation as to why these older forms were what they  were.

The dialects that formed Old English are not attested before their arrival in England.

It is not generally thought that there is an accusative case in English presently. Object pronouns are used for both direct and indirect objects. Those pronouns are usually referred to as "objective case". Some grammarians might differ on that. I do not think using the terms accusative or dative for those pronouns is wrong, but it does not seem useful except, perhaps, in instructing English to persons whose native language has proprietary pronouns for those cases.

Comment: [Syncretism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncretism_(linguistics)), where different grammatical forms share the same morphology, is common throughout Indo-european languages.

Comment: Fine, but that is a name, not an explanation

Comment: True. My point is that it occurs all over the place, not just in this one word in English.

Comment: I hope I did not impress anybody that I thought English was singular in that regard.. I recall thinking Latin and Greek were a little screwy until I came to the reality that many of the oddities in any of the so-called IE languages were common to others. Many seem directly related.